# classpath for compiling/running Apache Thrift on a Mac

Tags: java, homebrew, thrift

I installed thrift via brew.

```
brew install thrift
```

I am following this example: 
https://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-example.html

I am able to generate the code for java:

```
thrift --gen java multiple.thrift
```

I want to compile the MultiplicationService.java or MultiplicationHandler.java files.

```
javac MultiplicationService.java
MultiplicationService.java:15: error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist
```

what classpath should I use in mac when thrift is installed via brew?

```
javac -cp ?? MultiplicationService.java
```

Comment: Typically you use your build system (such as maven, ivy, gradle) and define a dependency on the thrift library in your build definition file.

Comment: I am not sure where libthrift is installed when using brew to install thrift. I am not sure if that's even installed or not.

Comment: Exactly, so don't depend on "brew install thrift". Set up a proper build file, like a pom.xml for maven, and define your dependency there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Erwin for his suggestion about using maven, I was able to make this thrift example work on my mac.

Here are the steps:

- Create a simple mvn project with the mvn quickstart: `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-thrift-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false`
- put all java files in the folder: `src/main/java/com/mycompany/app`
  the java files are: MultiplicationClient.java, MultiplicationServer.java, MultiplicationHandler.java (all 3 copy paste from the example), and MultiplicationService.java (generated by thrift --gen)
- add the following package to all 4 java files: `package com.mycompany.app;`
- add the dependency at the bottom of this post to the pom file. Make sure the version is the same as the thrift installed by brew.
- compile the project: `mvn package`
- run the server: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.MultiplicationServer"`
- run the client in another terminal: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.MultiplicationClient"`

dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
  <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
  <version>0.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```